# How do I have a bash script continually run during business hours?

Tags: python, bash, cron, ubuntu-server

I have a Python program I run at all times of the day that alerts me when something I am looking for online is posted. I want to give this to my employees but I only want to have it email them during business hours.

I have a Ubuntu server and use a .sh. I have a command in crontab that runs on startup.

How do I make my command run from 9-5?

Comment: wouldn't it be better to queue up emails and only limit sending to between 9 and 5, with bash?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a cronjob that starts the script every 5 minutes (or whatever often you want it to run) and additionally modify the script such that it creates a `.lock` file which it removes on exiting, but if it encounters it at the beginning it won't do anything (this way you don't have a long-running script active multiple times).

Comment: Just to note, the crontab entry would be something like `*/5 9-17 * * 1-5 /path/to/script`, that is, "every five minutes, between the hours of 9 AM and 5 PM, every day of the month, every day month, on weekdays only".

Comment: I think that's worth an answer by itself @mipadi !